# removing ' delimiters from a string

Tags: c#, string

hello i am trying to split a string using the split method of string

```
 string toSplit = "hello how 'are u"
 string[] arr = toSplit.Split('''); // that code doesnt compile 
 for (int i=0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
      Console.write("arr[i]="+ arr[i]);
```

my output is:

```
arr[0] = hello 
arr[1]=how, // i get this output by removing the split ofc , it doesnt compile 
arr[2]='are 
and arr[3]=u
```

and what i want is to remove this ' delimiter from arr[2]

thanks in advance for you kind help.

Comment: If you want split by space and remove single quote with double quote then toSplitWithoutQuotes = toSplit.Replace("'",string.Empty); and string[] arr = toSplitWithoutQuotes.Split(' '.ToCharArray());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
toSplit = toSplit.Replace("'", "");
```

before you split

But I am not quite understanding your question. Your title says you want to remove ' from a string.

I am also unsure how your code gets 4 objects in an array by splitting by ' since there is only one in your string.

The array would look like that if you did a split with a space character.

So do this to get the output you want:

```
string toSplit = "hello how 'are u";
toSplit = toSplit.Replace("'", ""); 
string[] arr = toSplit.Split(' '); 
for (int i=0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) 
    Console.Write("arr[i]="+ arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string toSplit = "hello how 'are u";
string[] arr = toSplit.Split('\'');
var arr=arr.Split(' ');
 for (int i=0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
      Console.Write("arr[i]="+ arr[i]);
```

Mistakes in code:

1. No semi colon in the string declaration line
2. You were not escaping `'` Use escape character `\`
3. **Console.Write** and not *write*